# How to accomplish the multi-dimensional fancy indexing in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a **3D tensor** (`[batch_size, seq_length, hidden_dim]`) and a **2D list** (`[batch_size, seq_length]`).

I want to using list to accomplish the selection of this tensor.

For example: the shape of 3D tensor `t [2, 5, 3]` and the shape of 2D list `l  [2, 5]`.

Let `t0 = t[0, :, :]` and `l0 = l[0]`. I would like to select "`t0[l0]`".

Same for `t1[l1]`, and so on.

I can only think of writng a `for` loop for achieve this:

```
new_ts = [] 
for i in range(t.shape[0]):
    new_t = t[i][l[i]]
    new_ts.append(new_t) 
new_t = torch.cat(new_ts, dim=2)
```

There must be a more simple way to accomplish this. **I have also tried multi-dimensional fancy indexing** `t[l]`, but the syntax is not valid and it doesn't work.

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided doesn't work, it seems you are looking to concatenate the tensors in the list on an axis that doesn't yet exit. I suggest you use [`stack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.stack.html) instead.

I don't think you can achieve this without a single loop. In terms of syntax and readability you can do a little better, in my opinion...

Having both starting tensors `t` and `l`:

```
t = torch.rand(2,5,3)
l = torch.randint(0,5, size=(2,5))
```

Using a list comprehension:

```
torch.stack([t[i][jj] for i, jj in enumerate(l)])
```